# Error: TypeError: Undefined is not a function While migrating to Express 4.12.1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I had this bit of code:

```
  app.configure(function() {
  this.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
  this.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  this.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/login')));
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/elyes')));
  // Allow parsing cookies from request headers
  this.use(express.cookieParser());

  this.use(express.session({ "secret": sessionSecret, "store": sessionStore }));
  // Allow parsing form data
  this.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

Which I have changed it to this code because I had to remove the app.configure() to be able to run it with Express 4:

```
  this.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
  this.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  this.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/login')));
  this.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/elyes')));
  // Allow parsing cookies from request headers
  this.use(cookieparser());
```

But this error occured when I tried to compile it with Node:
"this.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
TypeError: undefined is not a function"

So how can I remove the "app.configure()" part without problems?

Comment: Instead of `this.something`, try `app.something`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But the same error happened with this line too:

sockets.authorization(function (handshakeData, callback){ with the arrow of node pointing at the "a" of "authorization".

Comment: This is because your `sockets` variable doesn't have the mehtod `authorization`. Try to check how you're setting it.

Comment: Express 4.12.1 doesn't have app.configure function.  Check the doc's